# How to know if neutralizer is needed after chemical paint stripping?

Tags: paint-removal, chemicals

I just used `Klean Strip` paint stripper to remove some old paint from an exposed piece of wood near my stairs. The wood is pretty clean (grain visible and almost no traces of paint left) but I do plan to sand it. However, I know that some stripping products (like `PeelAway`) require (or recommend) neutralization as they themselves are not pH neutral.

What is the test to determine whether my surface needs neutralizing after chemical paint removal? I know there are pH (litmus) strips but I don't know which pH I should be targeting for and what neutralizing agent to use in different cases.

Comment: You know by reading the product label whether a simple rinse is required, or a solvent wash, or what. Klean Strip makes a bunch of different products... if you edit your question with the exact product used, I am sure someone will do a simple internet search for you.

Comment: What to the instructions on the container say to do? If it says to use something to neutralize it, then do so, if it doesn't, then don't.

Comment: Paint strippers that I use are solvent based not ph as in acid or base that litmus would show. The solvent turns the hardened paint into a goo that is wiped off. Mineral spirits are used for cleaning residue, if you are using something with a strong acid or base rinsing will usually take care of the issue.